# Want to generated a email after validating the file name ingested into gcs bucket

Tags: validation, email, google-cloud-platform, sendmessage, bucket

Want to generated a email after validating the file name ingested in to gcs bucket in gcp

Example the file has 001,003,004,005,007 are the files and here 002 and 006 are missing
How to automate to
Sent mail saying there is no files  for 002 and 006

Answer (score 1):

As a general mechanism, you might like to use a cloud function, which is triggered by a `finalize` event from the given GCS bucket. As the `finalize` event is generated per object/file, thus validation scope may be restricted in this case.

If you would like to check a manifold of objects/files in a bucket - you might need to define some time period (or regular periods) by the end of which some or all files/objects are to be presented in a GCS bucket. In that case a cloud function can be triggered by a Cloud Scheduler through a PubSub topic, for example.

That cloud function can implement any validation functionality you would like, and include functionality to send emails as well - whatever you would like to develop.

Comment: Note that in order to send email one has to use a third party email API i.e. SendGrid Email API, for which one needs to purchase a SendGrid subscription from [the GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/sendgrid-app/sendgrid-email) and then enable the API. Also, you can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) to understand more on Google Cloud Storage Triggers.